# Get Google Android Subscription API expiration time for a subscription token.

Tags: android, google-api, google-play

When I make the following request, Google only gives error 503, and won't provide any useful information.

I'm following the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1/purchases/get

The authorization token is recently refreshed (automatically). (Normally it says 401 when it's stale.)

```
[root@308321 cgi-bin]# wget -dSO- 'https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications/com.kizbit.pairfinder/subscriptions/subscription99/purchases/vkorjajxnjfyhxbftpymwfox?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZSnxLdOVf2QWrX96VbpDMdUKlHFXJOFEdHM_f_ErQlL'
Setting --server-response (serverresponse) to 1
Setting --output-document (outputdocument) to -
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.12 on linux-gnu.

--2012-07-05 00:09:46--  https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications/com.kizbit.pairfinder/subscriptions/subscription99/purchases/vkorjajxnjfyhxbftpymwfox?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZSnxLdOVf2QWrX96VbpDMdUKlHFXJOFEdHM_f_ErQlL
Resolving www.googleapis.com... 2001:4860:b007::5f, 74.125.142.95
Caching www.googleapis.com => 2001:4860:b007::5f 74.125.142.95
Connecting to www.googleapis.com|2001:4860:b007::5f|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x0000000000cc9370 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
Handshake successful; connected socket 3 to SSL handle 0x0000000000cd8e70
certificate:
  subject: /C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.googleapis.com
  issuer:  /C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority
X509 certificate successfully verified and matches host www.googleapis.com

---request begin---
GET /androidpublisher/v1/applications/com.kizbit.pairfinder/subscriptions/subscription99/purchases/vkorjajxnjfyhxbftpymwfox?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZSnxLdOVf2QWrX96VbpDMdUKlHFXJOFEdHM_f_ErQlL HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (linux-gnu)
Accept: */*
Host: www.googleapis.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 05 Jul 2012 04:09:56 GMT
Expires: Thu, 05 Jul 2012 04:09:56 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE

---response end---

  HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Date: Thu, 05 Jul 2012 04:09:56 GMT
  Expires: Thu, 05 Jul 2012 04:09:56 GMT
  Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Server: GSE
Closed 3/SSL 0x0000000000cd8e70
2012-07-05 00:09:47 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet? I experienced the same issue.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how. It just started working. I think it is one of the following: 1) The access token is only good for a very short time, maybe 10s, so you have to use a script or code to authenticate and fetch details in succession. 2) The package has to be published. 3) The subscription token has to be real & paid for. 4) The subscription id has to be published.

Comment: yes, seems Google has fixed the issue.

Comment: @Chloe : hi, how you get Access_Token?Plz guide me or if possible then provide some simple code.

Comment: @imrankhan. Here's how to do it in Perl: It won't let me paste here. See one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@imrankhan. Here's how to do it in Perl:

```
sub refreshAccessToken {
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
    $req->content_type('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    $req->content('grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=9999999.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&refresh_token='.$REFRESH_TOKEN);
    # grant_type=refresh_token
    # client_id=<the client ID token created in the APIs Console>
    # client_secret=<the client secret corresponding to the client ID>
    # refresh_token=<the refresh token from the very first authorization step>
    my $res = $ua->request($req);
    if ($res->is_success()) { # parse JSON
        #print $res->content . "\n";
        # {
          # "access_token" : "ya29.AHES3ZQ_MxxxxTeSl530Na2",
          # "token_type" : "Bearer",
          # "expires_in" : 3600,
        # }
        my $json = decode_json($res->content);
        my $accessToken = $json->{'access_token'};
        saveAccessToken($accessToken);
    } else {
        serverError($ERROR_GOOGLE, 'Could not refresh subscription access token from Google server. '.$res->status_line);
        exit;
    }
}
```